# Using libgit2 with Qt and MSVC throws Unresolved External Symbol but works in VC++ project

Tags: c++, qt, visual-c++, qmake, libgit2

I'm trying to compile with MSVC 2017 64bits a Qt application that uses libgit2. 
Trying to compile I've got the following error:

```
error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol git_repository_init referenced in function main.
```

*Googling* a bit I've found these answers ([Qt Creator: Unresolved External Symbol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14860814/qt-creator-unresolved-external-symbol) and [How to use libgit2 from a native C++ application on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16940753/how-to-use-libgit2-from-a-native-c-application-on-windows-microsoft-vc))

However, after trying the solution (`cmake %PATH_TO_LIBGIT2_SOURCE% -DTHREADSAFE=ON -DSTDCALL=OFF` and build again) nothing changed. Then I decided to use the exact same library (same build) with Visual Studio and Visual C++ and I'm not getting the error.

Visual C++ (compiles and works):

```
int main()
{

    git_libgit2_init();
    git_repository *repo = NULL;
    /* With working directory: */
    int error = git_repository_init(&repo, "C:/Users/myUser/Documents/tests", false);
    git_libgit2_shutdown();

    return 0;
}
```

Qt (does not compile):

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    git_libgit2_init();
    git_repository *repo = NULL;
    /* With working directory: */
    git_repository_init(&repo, "C:/Users/myUser/Documents/tests", false);
    git_libgit2_shutdown();

    return a.exec();
}
```

This is how I added the library to my Qt project (qmake project):

```
win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../libgit2/build/release/ -lgit2
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../libgit2/build/debug/ -lgit2
else:unix: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../libgit2/build/ -lgit2

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../libgit2/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../libgit2/include
```

Why it is working with the Visual C++ project but not with my Qt project if they are using the exactly same library (same path)? Am I missing something?

EDIT: The project compiles and works fine with minGW instead of MSVC but I want to use the last one.

Comment: What do you get if you add a new line to your .pro that contains `message($$clean_path(../libgit2/build/debug/))`? Does the path look correct?

Comment: @Mitch clean_path returns `../libgit2/build/debug` and absolute_path returns `C:/Users/myUser/Documents/qt/libgit2/build/debug` and both are correct.

Comment: I've edited adding some additional info.

Comment: What is the calling convention that your Qt application is using?  Is it using `stdcall`?  Have you tried building the `stdcall` version of libgit2?

Comment: I'm not sure of how I can check it but if I am not worng, it doesn't use stdcall (I mean by default). I've tried building libgit2 with `stdcall` and the Qt app with `QMAKE_CFLAGS += /Gz QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += /Gz` to use stdcall but nothing changed. I might be doing something wrong.